# Mostrar telas diferentes dinamicamente usando UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Bom galera, vou explicar o que preciso fazer. 
 Preciso criar uma tabela, onde cada linha tocada, terá que mostrar uma tela (Na verdade, um esqueleto padrão) e preencher essa nova tela com os dados referentes a ela.

E que seja de forma dinâmica, pois a tabela será uma lista de itens que serão adicionados e removidos.

Por exemplo: o app Relógio do iPhone, a função de Despertador. Quando você toca  em uma linha para editar um alarme, a tela que abrirá para edição é a mesma, porém os dados são referentes aquela linha que você escolheu.

Será uma grande ajuda! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso por dois meios.

O primeiro basta você definir uma propriedade na próxima `UIViewController` do tipo de objecto que você quer mostrar as informações. Feito isso, você instancia a `UIViewController` que você deseja mostrar as informações.

Por exemplo:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
DetalhesEAlteracoesViewController *detalhesViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Detalhes"];
[detalhesViewController setObjeto: objetoASerDescrito];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detalhesViewController animated:YES];
}
```

O segundo você pode usar outro meio, que é através dos métodos delegate de navegação. Basta usar a função `performSegueWithIdentifier:` e também definir uma propriedade na `UIViewController` que deseja apresentar as informações.

Exemplo:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Detalhes" sender: self];
}
```

No método delegate de navegação você instancia a `UIViewController` se defini o objeto:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"Detalhes"]) {
    DetalhesEAlteracoesViewController *detalhesViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [detalhesViewController setObjeto: objetoASerDescrito];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detalhesViewController animated:YES];        
}
}
```

Comment: Vou tentar e retorno com o resultado! Obrigado!!

Comment: Bom seu código me ajudou! Mas fiz a navegação usando static cell. Então a célula se comporta feito um button pelo storyboard e é possível utilizar a navegação por push ou model transiction. Mas obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  NSArray segues = @[ @"SegueLinha1", @"SegueLinha2", @"SegueLinha3" ];
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:segues[indexPath.row] sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Você pode inicializar a variável `segue` fora do método para evitar processamento redundante

Comment: Acho que você quis dizer indexPath.row :)

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Obrigado Otávio